# How to increase running performance over years?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, running-training-plan

It's been almost four years since the first time I started running, here is my background:

I'm 26, I practiced gymnastic for about seven years, from age three to eleven, I swam regularly but not anymore, and I go snowboarding sometimes.

I run three times a week, and fill the gaps with core and strength exercises three or four times a week (45 minutes, warm up, core, cool down), I don't go to the gym, but do a workout at home with no couch of course, I use Nike training club.

I notice that my performance hasn't changed much, during these four years, I mean after a **10K** I feel about the same as I did four years ago. I have never succeeded to run more than **22k**, and whenever I tried to boost my records by following a plan, like increasing my average distance from 30 km to 50 or more I ended up injuring myself. I tried to run four times per week, my plan had four different running styles, a long run usually between 15 and 18 kilometre, followed by a recovery run at low pace about 6 kilometre,  an interval of 30 minutes and a medium run about 8 or 7 kilometre. Here is an overview of my typical long run 15k, the horizontal axis represent time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

About injuries, shin splint at sides, both legs and recently I found out, my front joints (ankle) are permanently deformed; it happened during summer after a two though sessions, 18km and a 12km. I need to pay visits to kinesis physical therapy practice to get rid of inflammation.

I change my shoes when they hit 800 km, my right leg (injured) over pronates, but I always buy the right shoes.

I'm about **1.65m** and **57 kg**, I have an amazing diet and I don't suffer from any disease or chronic injuries.

I really want to run longer and more times per week, but seems impossible.

Could the reason be that I started running too late? Is my age letting me down? Could it be related to my genetic? Or I do need to build up for a stronger body?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you tried to boost your records/running totals? Generally the answer to how to get better at distance running is simply to run more, but without knowing what you tried that isn't a great answer.

Comment: @JohnP I edited my post, added more detail, if it's still vague or you need more information then don't hesitate to ask me for them.

Comment: I will write up a decent answer, but the basics are you are trying to ramp too much distance too fast, and I (personally) think that you are going too long between shoe changes. I am heavier than you (by abt  20 kilos), but I only get about 300-400km depending on the shoe, brand, etc. Worn shoes will definitely contribute to shin splints and overuse injuries. Could you add your typical long run time in minutes?

Comment: @JohnP Usually it takes me an hour and a half, plus minutes ten minutes, i added more photos to my post, those data i collected which my watch they are't very reliable and accurate but ... . Thank you.

Comment: @JohnP 300-400km isn't that much. I typically change my shoes around 800 - 1000km.(Rotating 3 training shoes though) without the risk of injury.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you get injured. How often do you change your shoes? For people that run, that is often one of the most common ways to get injured is when shoes start to wear out, and they don't provide the cushioning.

If you want to run faster, the simple solution is to run more. One of the most succinct ways I've seen it phrased is "Run. Run lots. Mostly slow, sometimes fast." Our college xcountry team was in the range of 90-110 miles a week (~160km) in season.

The other common injury reason is adding too much mileage too soon. You want to first get to the point where you are running the same mileage per week, but over 5-6 days. Then you can slowly start adding mileage. One program I recommend is 3:2:1, where you have 1 long run per week. Say it takes you 40 minutes to do whatever your long run is, then 2 days a week your time is 20 minutes, and 3 times a week your time is 10 minutes. You add time to the short runs which in turn increases medium and long runs, with no more than a 5% increase every couple weeks.

When you are running consistently 6x per week and have total mileage in the 60k range, you can look at adding speed work to get faster (And you will note some speed gains just from increasing mileage). There are two types of speedwork, threshold and interval. (Also fartleks, but that's a type of threshold). Intervals are short distance (400-800m) done at faster than race pace, with long rests to be able to make all the times. Threshold is *near* race pace, on shorter rests. Intervals increase your top end speed, threshold increases the time you can spend at that speed. No more than one serious interval session a week.

The other thing to consider is running form, there may be something in your form that is causing injuries past a certain distance point, but that's beyond our ability to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ground you run on to decrease the strain you put on your legs. Preferably run on softer ground like grass.
Also work on the strength of the foot itself. The stronger the arch of the foot the better it can absorb the shocks of hitting the ground.
You might as well want to look into running techniques. Forefoot landing is believed to be better and more natural and therefore also reducing injuries. But science is not so clear on this one maybe due to research sponsored by shoe manufactures. So you might want to give it a try.
Generally inflammation is a result of stress on the body. This might be due to going too long too quickly.

Comment: Forefoot/chi/pose running (IMHO) is a gimmick created out of a misunderstanding of what heelstriking actually is.

Comment: I always run on soft spots, forefoot landing didn't end well, i tried it three years ago end up staying at home for about two and half months, running techniques can be a solution, i recently tried exercising with foam roller, it helped, it does indeed heal my long lasting  shin splint. And i feel less stresses during running

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to train at different paces for different runs to improve your potential for race day.  Look up Dr. Jack Daniels' vdot calculators.  It plots your fitness level to an algorithm based on thousands of runners times.  It projects your finishing time for certain race distances, as long as you train properly and don’t mess up on race day.
As for training, most of your training volume is at a slower pace, so it’s not mentally and physically taxing.  On other training days, you have to be mentally there, to focus on running harder and faster than race pace (but shorter distance).  The training is structured, certain paces for specific training runs.